# Wrapping text around a div

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have a layout like this:

```
Header div
divLeft divRight
Footer div
```

divLeft is a bunch of text and divRight is a div with some stuff in it.  divLeft is a lot longer and I would like the text to wrap under divright.  right now it's just making two columns and there's a lot of white space under divRight.  Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Put `divRight` inside `divLeft` and float it.

Try this:

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
#primary, #header, #footer {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#secondary {
   float: right;
      width: 200px; /* or whatever width you want */
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="primary">
   <div id="secondary">
      <p>Put your content here that goes on the right</p>
   </div>
   <p>Put your content here<br /> 
      that goes on the left<br /> 
      and should wrap under the right-hand column</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can float divRight right. That should allow the left div to wrap under the right text.

**Edit:** You will also need divRight inside of divLeft as described by Donut.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very nice solution; take a look at the source of the example [here](http://riddle.pl/-/xhtml/css-equalcolumns/eqcolumns-okie.html).

Answer (score 0):

Place divRight inside divLeft and give it these properties:

```
.divRight {
    display: inline-block;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    vertical-align: top;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
```